# Java ULC - how to modify binary payload?

Tags: java, security, penetration-testing

I'm working on security assessment of thick client application created using Java ULC (ultra light client). It is black box approach so I don't have any insight in source code and I'm having hard time finding any useful resource for ULC on internet.

So far I wrote a proxy which intercepts communication which is HTTP GET/POST with binary payload. When I decompress payload and convert binary to hex and then hex to ascii I can see string like cleartext username, password, some keywords like: java.lang.Object, setColumnClasses and bunch of null bytes and non printable characters. Response also contains strings like: wrong username or password I could use for testing.

Does any one what kind of protocol is used for communication? Is there some kind of RFC? It is not classic Java serialization since there is no \xac \xde at the beginning. What I would like to do is to modify traffic on the fly so instead of username I can inject various SQL injection attempts and test backend database.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try changing the encoding of the character set to Unicode instead of ASCII for the non-printable characters?

Comment: I just tried, it looks the same. :/